# What's wrong with my Xpath?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have an xml file and I am trying to get a list of all of a particular node using c#.

A trimmed down version of my xml is:

```
<file>
    <AnotherNode>
    </AnotherNode> 
    <ROWS> 
        <row> 
            <code>Code1</code> 
            <R>1</R> 
            <G>2</G> 
            <B>3</B> 
        </row> 
        <row> 
            <code>Code2</code> 
            <R>1</R> 
            <G>2</G> 
            <B>3</B> 
        </row>
    </ROWS>
</file>
```

There are multiple "row" nodes and I want a list of all the codes from within those nodes

The XPath I am using is:

```
/file/ROWS/row/code
```

with this code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xml);
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes(xpath here);
foreach (XmlNode code in nodeList)
{
}
```

but I am returning no nodes.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program and XML file displaying the problem. Often XPath issues are caused by namespace problems, which we may not see in your "trimmed down" version.

Comment: Your XPath expression says that `<file>` is the document element. Is that actually the case?

Comment: Your `xpath` works fine for me. I'd therefore suggest that it's your C#, but I can't help you there.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, there is no namespace on my xml,the only other bit of my program is passing my xml as a stream to a function that contains the above code

Comment: @Frederic Yes files is the document element

Comment: @MattH, that's what I thought but can't work it out?! Will try my xpath on my trimmed down xml

Comment: @Bex: Still, a short but complete console app and XML to go with it would make it a lot easier to see what's going on...

Comment: @Jon Thanks, but an answer below found my problem as I was preparing it!

Comment: @Bex: Please take a look on my answer

Comment: @Bex: That's *another* good reason to prepare a short but complete program - quite often you *will* find the answer while you're preparing it. It's a good way of diagnosing the problem yourself.

Comment: @Jon, no I didn't mean that, I meant the answer appeared as I was preparing the program, so I added it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution and suggestion if you are using at least .net 3.5.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//file/ROWS/row/code"))
{

}
```

Be sure to include "using System.Xml.XPath;"

Answer (score 3):

Remove the following line from your code:

```
root.InnerText = root.InnerText.ToLower();
```

This creates an XML with all tags in lower case and your XPath that is correct for the original tag names won't work anymore.

Comment: oops, this isn't the problem, I tried doing this to try using a lower case xpath (which still didn't work) Edited

Comment: @Bex: And this is precisely the kind of reason why a short but complete program is helpful. It means that everyone's dealing with the same code, having removed silly niggles.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line from your code:

```
root.InnerText = root.InnerText.ToLower();
```

I tried converting your xpath to lowercase and leaving this line in, but resetting the root.InnerText seems to destroy the structure of the XML document (stepping through the code in the debugger changes the `root.ChildNodes.Count` property from 2 to 1 after the above line has executed).

Answer (score 0):

Your query would work if you had next XML structure:

```
<code>
    <R>1</R> 
    <G>2</G> 
    <B>3</B>
</code>
```

where R,G,B are subnodes of code.

But in your case, R,G,B as well as code are subnodes of row:

```
<row>
    <code> </code>
    <R>1</R> 
    <G>2</G> 
    <B>3</B>
</row>
```

So query `file/ROWS/row/*[not(self::code)]` will collect all R,G,B values (all subnodes of row except code).

And call `doc.SelectNodes()`, not `doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes()`!